# Libwww-perl certificate authority usage

Tags: perl, ssl, web, https, certificate

When using Perl's libwww-perl or WWW::Mechanize, what is the proper usage of the `HTTPS_CA_FILE` and `HTTPS_CA_DIR` environment variables to register HTTPS certificate trust chains?  Can/should both of them be used at once, or should exactly one of them be defined?  What certificate formats do they take -- `.pem` files only?  Is using `HTTPS_CA_FILE` equivalent to using `HTTPS_CA_DIR` with only the one certificate file in the directory?